# Tiling a square with right-angled triangles

Tags: tiling

Tile a square with twenty congruent right-angled triangles.  For each triangle, one leg is of length 1 and the other leg is of length 2.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Note first that

> the area of the square is 20 times the area of the triangle, namely 20, so the side length is $2\sqrt5$.

That's

> twice the hypotenuse of the triangle

which immediately suggests the overall shape of the thing. With apologies for the horrific ASCII art:

> ```
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .
>             ..''|:
> .   .   ..''.___. : .   .
>     ..''|       |  :
> ..''.___.___.___.___:   .
>  :  |       |       |:
> . : .___.___.___.___. : .
>    :|       |       |  :
> .   :___.___.___.___.___:   .   .
>      :  |       |   ..''`
> .   . : .___.___..''.   .   .   .
>        :|   ..''
> .   .   :.''.   .   .   .   .   .
> ```

where

> each of those 2x1 rectangles is of course divided into two triangles by one of its diagonals.

Here, have some slightly less horrific not-ASCII not-art:

> [image]

Comment: I like this answer because it explains the math involved plus it gives two views of a solution in two different ways:  ASCII art vs Graphic image **AND** Tilted vs Non-tilted square.  I also appreciate the guide dots and the guidelines.

Comment: That ascii art is fantastic!

Comment: I upvoted this just for the ASCII art :)

Answer (score 24):

May I offer a more aesthetic tiling?

> [image]

Comment: More aesthetic than ASCII at you mean? `:)`

Comment: @MOehm Certainly - Gareth added the image about seven minutes after I posted. Even so, I find the mirror symmetry more pleasing to the eye.

Comment: Which Transformer is this?

Comment: reminds me a bit of a rot13(fgne qrfgeblre) shape... (saw that as the first after unspoilering the solution)

Answer (score 17):

Using the solution of this classic puzzle, *"If the dotted lines connect the midpoint of each edge with a vertex, find the fraction of the area of the yellow square to the large red one"*:

> [image: classic puzzle]

namely,

> 1/5 i.e. the same as each of the 4 red triangles.

Each red triangle and the yellow square can be divided into 4 of the triangles given in the question, resulting in this neat solution:

> [image: solution]